# MVC empty query string parameter strange behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, model-binding

I'm trying to implement search by passing the keyword to controller action as a parameter as shown below:

```
public ActionResult Index(string query)
{
    var contacts = _unitOfWork.Contacts.GetContacts(_user.Id, query);
    var viewModel = contacts.Select(Mapper.Map<Contact, ContactViewModel>);
    return View("Index", viewModel); 
}
```

`GetContacts` function in the repository looks like the following:

```
public IEnumerable<Contact> GetContacts(int userId, string query = null)
{
    var list = _context.Contacts
                    .Where(c => c.UserId == userId)
                    .OrderBy(c => c.FirstName)
                    .AsQueryable();

    if (query != null)
        list = list.Where(c => c.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower())
        || c.LastName.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower()));

    return list.ToList();
}
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:50139/contacts/index?query=`, I get an empty list. Having stepped through the code it is apparent that the `query` parameter is converted to an empty string value.
To ensure the search works, I have the following tests and all of them pass:

```
GetContacts_SearchByFirstName_ShouldReturnFilteredList
GetContacts_SearchByLastName_ShouldReturnFilteredList
GetContacts_SearchWithCapitalLetters_ShouldReturnFilteredList
GetContacts_SearchWithNullQuery_ShouldReturnAllContacts
```

In particular, the following test runs the function with empty string, which also passes successfully.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetContacts_SearchWithEmptyString_ShouldReturnAllContacts()
{
    var contactList = new List<Contact>()
    {
        // Construct new contact with first and last name and associated user id. 
        new Contact("e", "b",_userId ),
        new Contact("c", "b",_userId ),
        new Contact("a", "b",_userId ),
        new Contact("d", "b",_userId )
    };

    _mockContacts.SetSource(contactList);

    var result = _repository.GetContacts(_userId, "");

    result.Count().Should().Be(4);
}
```

I have 3 contacts in the database and I can see all of them when I don't pass the query parameter. I would appreciate if you could point out why the controller action returns an empty list.

Comment: Try using String.IsNullOrEmpty instead of query != null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an empty string to the query parameter, the condition 
`if(query!=null)` fails and the line below that

```
list = list.Where(c => c.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower())
            || c.LastName.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower()));
```

gets executed, which checks the database for an entry with empty string in the `LastName`. This condition never gets satisfied and hence your list gets overridden with an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

change   `if (query != null)` to   `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))`

Comment: The question is _why the controller action returns an empty list?_

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes and the answer is because of wrong if Statement.

Comment: No, OP is claiming their unit test passes (but I suspect their claim is wrong because I can repeat it)